# KOSKK network model in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to replicate the KOSKK model (Kumpula et al. 2007) in NetLogo but I am stuck.

The original algorithm is:

> **(I)** Select a node i randomly, and
>
> - **(a)** select a friend’s friend k (by weighted search) and introduce
>     it to i with prob. p_1 (with initial tie strength w_0) if not already
>     acquainted. Increase tie strengths by "d" along the search path, as
>     well as on the link l_{ik} if it was already present.
> - **(b)** Additionally, with prob. p_r (or with prob. 1 if i has no connections), connect i to a random node j (with tie strength w_0).
>
> **(II)** Select a random node and with prob. p_d remove all of its ties.

In particular, I am struggling to write correctly the initial step I-a. How can I tell the program to pick the friend k of a friend j (!= myself, i) in the highest weighted path (l_{ij},l_{jk})?

Comment: What do you have so far? You will definitely need the networks extension. There are primitives in that to find weighted paths, for example.

Comment: So far, I only know how to recall a random friend of a friend of a node using the function                                                                              to-report find-partner2

report one-of other turtles-on (turtle-set ([link-neighbors] of link-neighbors))
end                                                                                                              The net ext allows me to calculate the total weight of a path but I have got two issues then. 1) how to select the path with highest total weight, and 2) how to select from that path the terminal node.